# What is a good strategy to integrate radio buttons?

Tags: radio-button, javafx, java-7

[image]

Basically I have three radio buttons and only want one button selected at at time, of course when created they are independent of each other. Currently, I use change listeners to interweave the buttons and it works in my context just fine. But, I realize this really isn't the best way because the code becomes cumbersome when more buttons are needed or if a particular section of code goes under many changes and several other reasons. So, how can I better integrate radio buttons (or anything where behavior depends on the integration of multiple controls <-- if someone wants to rephrase this please do so)?

Comment: Use a [ButtonGroup](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/buttongroup.html).

Comment: A `ButtonGroup` is for Swing, not for JavaFX jaco

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a [ToggleGroup](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/ToggleGroup.html):

> A class which contains a reference to all Toggles whose selected
>   variables should be managed such that only a single Toggle within the
>   ToggleGroup may be selected at any one time.

There is an example in the [RadioButton](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/RadioButton.html) javadoc:

```
ToggleGroup group = new ToggleGroup();
RadioButton button1 = new RadioButton("select first");
button1.setToggleGroup(group);
button1.setSelected(true);
RadioButton button2 = new RadioButton("select second");
button2.setToggleGroup(group);
```